# Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead by object properties

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a similar object (imitation of Map):

```
$scope.vehicles = {
   1:{id:1, model:'Sedan'},
   2:{id:2, model:'SUV'},
   3:{id:3, model:'Van'}
}
```

I need in using values of properties in typeahead of ui bootstrap (with saving filtering by 'model' property)

Next variant is not working:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vehicle"
   uib-typeahead="vehicle as vehicle.model for (id, vehicle) in vehicles | filter:{model:$viewValue} | limitTo:10">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for using list of object properties need special function

```
$scope.getVehicleList = function () {
   return Object.values($scope.vehicles);
}
```

Typeahead element:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vehicle"
       uib-typeahead="vehicle as vehicle.model for vehicle in getVehicleList() | filter:{model:$viewValue} | limitTo:10">
```